# I'm getting the error "Undefined control sequence"?

Tags: tables

I am getting the error "undefined control sequence" on running the MWE given below. Please help me sort it out....

```
     \documentclass[journal,12pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{multirow}      
    \usepackage{multicol}   
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Optimized Parameter Values}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \scalebox{1}
    {
     \begin{tabular}  
         {|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
          \multicolumn{7}{}{} \\ \hline
        Type of Controller & Parameter & Xmax & Xmin & Iter. reqd. for  
                convergence & Optimized value & $Wmin$ \\ \hline
        \multirow{6}{*}{PSO-SOSMC} & $c_1$ & 5 & 0.1 & 37 & 4.75& 68.43 \\   
        \cline{2-7}
         & $c_2$ & 5 & 0.1 & 10 & 4.273& 20.45 \\ \cline{2-7}
         & $\lambda_1 $& 5 & 0.1 & 37 & 2.75 & 68.43\\ \cline{2-7}
         & $\lambda_2 $& 5 & 0.1 & 10 & 3.59 & 20.45\\ \cline{2-7}
         & $W_1 $& 1 & 0.05 & 37 & 0.43 & 68.45\\ \cline{2-7}
         & $W_2 $& 1 & 0.05 & 10 & 0.218 & 20.43\\ \hline
          \multirow{4}{*}{PSO-BELBIC} & $W_1$ & 5 & 0.1 & 36 & 4.5 &   
           27.34 \\ \cline{2-7}
         & $W_2$ & 5 & 0.1 & 14 & 4.5 & 61.63 \\ \cline{2-7}
         & $G_1$ & 5 & 0.1 & 36 & 1.4 & 27.34 \\ \cline{2-7}
         & $G_2$ & 5 & 0.1 & 14 & 1.4 & 61.63\\ \hline
         \end{tabular}
      }
     \label{optimized_values}
     \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage{graphicx}` is missing (apart from the final `\end{document}`).

Comment: you need `graphicx` for `\scalebox` but what is the point of `\scalebox{1}` ? It just makes tex do a lot of work to multiply the size of everything by 1 ??? also if you do use scalebox do not  have space after the `{` and before the `}` as you have it or you get unwanted white space in the output.

Comment: I bet your paper is due within the next tenty minutes. I don't see another reason for [crossposting](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=28553)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scalebox` is defined by package `graphicx`, but you don't even need it. I would suppose a different approach to tables, though. Keep it simple.

[image: biswaIeeeUndefinedSequence]

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{graphicx}  %unneeded
\usepackage{multirow}  %unneeded    
%\usepackage{multicol}  %unneeded
\usepackage{showframe}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Optimized Parameter Values}
    \begin{tabular}{llllp{7em}p{7em}l}
        \toprule
        Type of Controller & Parameter    & Xmax & Xmin & \raggedright Iter. reqd. for convergence & Optimized value & $W_\mathrm{min}$ \\ \midrule
            PSO-SOSMC        & $c_1$        & 5    & 0.1  & 37                                       & 4.75            & 68.43 \\
                             & $c_2$        & 5    & 0.1  & 10                                       & 4.273           & 20.45 \\
                             & $\lambda_1 $ & 5    & 0.1  & 37                                       & 2.75            & 68.43\\
                             & $\lambda_2 $ & 5    & 0.1  & 10                                       & 3.59            & 20.45\\
                             & $W_1 $       & 1    & 0.05 & 37                                       & 0.43            & 68.45\\
                             & $W_2 $       & 1    & 0.05 & 10                                       & 0.218           & 20.43\\ \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
            PSO-BELBIC       & $W_1$        & 5    & 0.1  & 36                                       & 4.5             & 27.34 \\
                             & $W_2$        & 5    & 0.1  & 14                                       & 4.5             & 61.63 \\
                             & $G_1$        & 5    & 0.1  & 36                                       & 1.4             & 27.34 \\
                             & $G_2$        & 5    & 0.1  & 14                                       & 1.4             & 61.63\\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

        \vspace{2cm}
%   \scalebox{1}
%   {
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
            \multicolumn{7}{}{} \\ \hline
            Type of Controller & Parameter & Xmax & Xmin & Iter. reqd. for convergence & Optimized value & $Wmin$ \\ \hline
            \multirow{6}{*}{PSO-SOSMC} & $c_1$ & 5 & 0.1 & 37 & 4.75& 68.43 \\ \cline{2-7}
            & $c_2$ & 5 & 0.1 & 10 & 4.273& 20.45 \\ \cline{2-7}
            & $\lambda_1 $& 5 & 0.1 & 37 & 2.75 & 68.43\\ \cline{2-7}
            & $\lambda_2 $& 5 & 0.1 & 10 & 3.59 & 20.45\\ \cline{2-7}
            & $W_1 $& 1 & 0.05 & 37 & 0.43 & 68.45\\ \cline{2-7}
            & $W_2 $& 1 & 0.05 & 10 & 0.218 & 20.43\\ \hline
            \multirow{4}{*}{PSO-BELBIC} & $W_1$ & 5 & 0.1 & 36 & 4.5 & 27.34 \\ \cline{2-7}
            & $W_2$ & 5 & 0.1 & 14 & 4.5 & 61.63 \\ \cline{2-7}
            & $G_1$ & 5 & 0.1 & 36 & 1.4 & 27.34 \\ \cline{2-7}
            & $G_2$ & 5 & 0.1 & 14 & 1.4 & 61.63\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
%   }
    \label{optimized_values}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You, David , Gernot and Johannes :). It worked out well.      Sorry for the crossposting in the latex community, I thought the two communities are decoupled and I hadn't expected such prompt response.

Comment: Johannes, your tabular representation is very elegant....Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Johannes, I have failed to mention earlier that I need the scalebox and arraystretch commands to resize my table according to the need of the paper.
I have tweaked your code to include those two commands and it looks just fine. The code is shown below

```
    \documentclass[journal,12pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %unneeded 
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[h!]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{Optimized Parameter Values}
    \scalebox{0.8}
    {
    \begin{tabular}{llllp{7em}p{7em}l}
        \toprule
        Type of Controller & Parameter    & Xmax & Xmin & \raggedright Iter. reqd. for convergence & Optimized value & $W_\mathrm{min}$ \\ \midrule
            PSO-SOSMC        & $c_1$        & 5    & 0.1  & 37                                       & 4.75            & 68.43 \\
                             & $c_2$        & 5    & 0.1  & 10                                       & 4.273           & 20.45 \\
                             & $\lambda_1 $ & 5    & 0.1  & 37                                       & 2.75            & 68.43\\
                             & $\lambda_2 $ & 5    & 0.1  & 10                                       & 3.59            & 20.45\\
                             & $W_1 $       & 1    & 0.05 & 37                                       & 0.43            & 68.45\\
                             & $W_2 $       & 1    & 0.05 & 10                                       & 0.218           & 20.43\\ \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
            PSO-BELBIC       & $W_1$        & 5    & 0.1  & 36                                       & 4.5             & 27.34 \\
                             & $W_2$        & 5    & 0.1  & 14                                       & 4.5             & 61.63 \\
                             & $G_1$        & 5    & 0.1  & 36                                       & 1.4             & 27.34 \\
                             & $G_2$        & 5    & 0.1  & 14                                       & 1.4             & 61.63\\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
}
    \label{optimized_values}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove the wrong `%unneded` now. ;-) And the space that David talked about before.